# Need help incorporating a piece of code in a divi section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

in the Divi page builder on Wordpress you can add and Class or ID to a section. But I can't figure out a way to add any inline code to the  tags that the page builder then puts in the html that makes the page.

I'm trying to add the midnight.js plugin to a Wordpress site using Divi and to do so I need to add inline javascript code...

```
<div data-midnight="white">
```

This is the div code that the divi builder puts on the page:

```
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_parallax  et_pb_section_3 et_section_regular">
```

I need to add `data-midnight="white"` to the end of this code

Does anyone know a way I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you add this in a js file that's loaded or within a `<script>` tag into the HTML code, it should add the desired attribute to that element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".et_pb_section.et_pb_section_parallax.et_pb_section_3.et_section_regular").attr("data-midnight", "white");
});
```

It selects the element/s which has/have all those classes combined and adds the attribute with the indicated vaue to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to add inline code, you can use the code module that Divi provides. Just make sure you put any JavaScript inside `<script>` tags.

You could try using `setAttribute()`. So if you're wanting to change "div_current_id" to "date-midnight" as the ID, you could do:

```
var foo = document.querySelector("div_current_id");
foo.setAttribute("id", "date-midnight");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.I'm trying to add code to the <div> tag that the Divi Builder spits out once the page is loaded. I'm wondering if there's a way I can use Javascript to add inline code to these divs if I give them their own ID's.

Comment: I updated my answer...is that more what you're thinking?

Comment: You're definitely closer but I need to add the code within the div tag without changing any of the Id's or Classes so it'd be something like this"

Comment: <div id="blah blah" class="blah blah" data-midnight="white">

Comment: omg I just tweaked your code and figured it out! You're a saviour

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you figured it out.